# How to make in angular your component.ts load after body loads (no external files)

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to add, addEventlister to my id created with uuid, but it giving me back error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

````
export class CommentItemComponent implements OnInit {
  textReviewId: string;
  readMoreId: string;
  constructor() {  
    this.textReviewId = uuid();  
    this.readMoreId = uuid();  
}  
 


  ngOnInit(): void {
      var textReview = document.getElementById(this.textReviewId);
      var readMore = document.getElementById(this.readMoreId);
     
        window.onload=function(){
          readMore!.addEventListener('click',function(){
              if(textReview!.classList.contains('text-truncate')){
                  textReview!.classList.remove('text-truncate');
                  readMore!.innerHTML = "Read less";
                  console.log("jestes zjebem");
              }else{
                textReview?.classList.add('text-truncate');
                readMore!.innerHTML = "Read more...";

              }
          })
          };
    


  } ```
````

Comment: Mark answer if this resolved your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the code inside ngAfterViewInit and remove window.onload:

```
console.log(this.readMoreId);

var textReview = document.getElementById(this.textReviewId);
var readMore = document.getElementById(this.readMoreId);

readMore!.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if(textReview!.classList.contains('text-truncate')){
        textReview!.classList.remove('text-truncate');
        readMore!.innerHTML = "Read less";
        console.log("jestes zjebem");
    }else{
      textReview?.classList.add('text-truncate');
      readMore!.innerHTML = "Read more...";

    }
})
```